# SERVERFAIL error while doing nslookup on server itself. FreeBSD

Tags: domain-name-system, unix, freebsd

I am using FreeBSD to setup a DNS server.
I have install BIND and setup everything in `resolv.conf` and `named.conf` file.

This is the ip address of my DNS server `192.168.10.100`.

in `resolv.conf` I added the following line,

```
nameserver 192.168.10.100
```

I have also create a zone in `named.conf` file called `.pbv`, and then I have used `nsupdate` to add a domain to this zone which is `testing.pbv`

Now, when I `nslookup 192.168.10.100` on the server itself, it doesn't work and always return,

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.10.100, trying next server
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

However when I `nslookup` `testingpbv` it returns following,

```
Server:         192.168.10.100
Address:        192.168.10.100#53

Name:   testing.pbv
Address: 192.168.10.100
```

I don't understand why I cannot run `nslookup 192.168.10.100` ?

This is my `resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 192.168.10.100
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

It merits mentioning here that I can't even lookup google.com or any other external domain for that matter.

Comment: That reads like it's going to an outside DNS server.

Comment: @Davidw, sorry that was a mistake, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. Let's break it down.

- Unless you've configured a reverse zone for `10.168.192.in-addr.arpa`, your recursive server has to get this information from somewhere else. You have not mentioned setting up such a zone, so I will assume that it does not exist.
- [RFC 1918 private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) are not routed on the internet. If a DNS server has to perform full recursion on a reverse DNS request for this IP space, one of two things happens:

  1. Recursion is performed until [IANA's blackhole servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhole_server) are reached. They will return a response of `NXDOMAIN`.
  2. The server skips the step of reaching out to the internet because it knows it is pointless. It forges a response of `NXDOMAIN` and does not waste the bandwidth. BIND 9.9 and upward does this through something called [automatic empty zones](https://deepthought.isc.org/article/AA-00800/0/Automatic-empty-zones-including-RFC-1918-prefixes.html).

To simplify all of this, if you're seeing `SERVFAIL` here it means something is broken. Either the server is trying to get the answer from the internet and failing to do so, or you have a broken configuration and are not reading the logs closely enough. (as an example, this would happen if you had created a zone with illegal syntax for `10.168.192.in-addr.arpa`)

To rule out a network problem, you can try running `dig +trace 10.168.192.in-addr.arpa`. If this command returns an error, you will need to troubleshoot your network. If it does not return an error, examine your logs more carefully.

Comment: Thanks so much, I indeed had an error in my reverse zone file which I have now fixed. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`nslookup` on an IP will look for a corresponding `PTR` record, which is apparently missing from your configuration.

That said, I've worked for huge companies with hundreds of servers and none of them configured reverse lookups on local IPs.

Comment: `SERVFAIL` doesn't mean 'missing' but rather 'broken', though.

Comment: I suspect that adding the zone would stop it from failing.  Mine is configured to refuse recursion so it gives `REFUSED` instead.  There is obviously no proper way for `bind` to handle an unknown IP address.  It probably tries to find an authoritative server for it and fails, justifying the response.

Comment: That'd be an incorrect assumption. The servers at the top of the DNS hierarchy hold all authority until they delegate it elsewhere. This works the same way for both forward and reverse DNS. If `SERVFAIL` is encountered, it means that the recursive server ran into a problem following the referral chain to a properly responding authoritative server.

Comment: You're right, it should return `NXDOMAIN`.